# ASP.NET MVC: No record added to database after POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    UpdateModel(collection);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new {controller = "Home"});
}
```

The action succeed, but there was no recored inserted into the database. Why?

I do not want to manually create a object by getting each value from each field in form collection.

Comment: You have to insert the model,not update it. You should insert it by another repository function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UpdateModel(collection);
context.SaveChanges();
```

You didn't made any changes to the context in order to expect something to get saved. Entity Framework (assuming this is what you are using) works with objects. So you need a model and persist this model into the database. So your controller action could look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    _repository.Create(product);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new {controller = "Home"});
}
```

where the `_repository` variable is some interface which defines the operations on your models. Using an interface here allows you to separate your data access logic from your controller logic. In the implementation of this repository you could be using any data access technology you like such as EF or NHibernate, it's just that your controller shouldn't know about it.

Comment: @user469652, the correct way is to define a model (for example Customer), use this model as argument of your controller action and persist it. I would recommend you going through some of the tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/mvc. They contain many useful information and examples.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes feel it's not DRY when doing so, I mean need to create an separate view model. Thanks!

Comment: @user469652, that's what ORMs are about: fill the gap between SQL and OOP. Defining models is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the context is open and it's the same from which your object has been extracted  ? is the object is still connected to the context ? 
usually you create a new context in each call, you need to attach the object to the context change it state to modified and than use SaveChanges.
Otherwise, nothing is done.

```
 context.Customers.Attach(myCustomre);
 context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myCustomre, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

and for insert:

```
context.Customers.AddObject(newCustomer);
                context.SaveChanges();
```